# Can you extend Google Identity Toolkit to include facebook/twitter/etc?

Tags: facebook, openid, google-identity-toolkit

I decided to look into using Google Identity Toolkit. I knew I liked the UI, and the idea of using a "federated" login system. I'm now having my doubts, as while my site works well with gmail/ymail/hotmail etc, it doesn't seem to support any of the social platforms.

Essentially, I just need an email address from people to be registered with the site, so I thought GITKit was the perfect solution.

Should I have gone down a custom route (like stackoverflow?), or have I missed some of the GITKit documentation?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did do a fair amount of googling prior to posting that question. However, I have come accross some answers. Rather than delete my post - I guess I should share the information. If others thought the information was clear, please delete this thread!

Firstly, there is a page identifying how to add custom IDP's: https://sites.google.com/site/gitooldocs/customidps

There is also a sample site (http://www.openidsamplestore.com/localmapping/) which uses facebook.

> **How does the advanced demo work for identity providers who are not
> E-mail providers, such as social networks?**
>
> The hardest part about
> designing the advanced site was to find a way to handle all the
> edge-cases that can happen with these types of identity providers.
> Google previously published a summary of best-practices for
> account-linking that describes why these types of identity providers
> are so much harder to support.  However this demo provides a user
> self-service mechanism for all the tricky cases to avoid the costs
> that a website might otherwise occur if those users contact a customer
> support representative.

Finally, a best practices run-down is available here:

https://sites.google.com/site/oauthgoog/UXFedLogin/loginlogic

**EDIT 1 :**

> If that identity provider asserts email addresses that it does not
> host, we suggest you also implement additional account linking logic.
>
> A future version of GITKit will add support for these type of
> identity providers, such as social networks, which will avoid the need
> to implement that logic

Perhaps GITKit is the future after-all... Would be nice to have an idea of the time-frame in which this support will be added though...

**EDIT 2 :**

Direct from the horses mouth (Eric Sachs @ Google - [Source Link](http://code.google.com/apis/identitytoolkit/forum.html?place=msg/google-identity-toolkit/u0kLlInzfd4/GFtvmiE2GgwJ)):

> That feature is not expected to be generally available in 2011.  We
> are shooting for Q1 2012

Comment: Thanks for presenting this issue. I'm trying myself. Can you throw up any JSFiddle or github code, that describes how you tackled these issues? : 

**i)** How IDP auth, fits into your data model & how you implemented the callbackURL ; 
**ii)** What's the data and how's the session state managed by GITkit? ; 
**iii)** Is there a way to set this up the 'callbackURL' for development? The IDP needs a URL that it can redirect back to ; 
**iv)** How does GITkit / Account Chooser workflow let users register an account that's native to your app? ; 

Thanks in advance

Comment: @Frye - For more general queries, the GITKit google group is monitored by Google Employees. It seems your answers have been addressed here: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-identity-toolkit/2mRCtg_scRc/xo5mcSpiFo0J

For setting up GITKit in .Net MVC, there is a decent guide here: 
http://havethunk.wordpress.com/2011/08/10/google-identity-toolkit-asp-net-mvc3/


Hope that helps!

Comment: Yes indeed. I'm going on that reply. Thanks for the feedback 'dazbradbury'. Cheers.

Comment: the link https://sites.google.com/site/gitooldocs/customidps asks for requesting access.

Comment: ok now i realize most of these links are busted in this answer and seems kinda dated

Answer (score 1):

Looks like someone got it working back in Dec 2011 but there is still an outstanding issue with mapping the id returned to an email address. It was probably resolved:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/google-identity-toolkit/facebook/google-identity-toolkit/2218yW4zXw8/28X7btJEh_sJ

Here is the documentation for the sample store including brief info on basic, mobile and advanced mode (using facebook):
https://sites.google.com/site/oauthgoog/Home/openidsamplesite

An out-of-the-box IDP for facebook and twitter has not yet been released.